# Ubuntu 22.04 Save to PDF Printer Large File Size

Tags: printing, 22.04, pdf

I have recently upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04 and since then, "Save to PDF" printing creates huge PDFs.

As a comparison, I have monthly reports that I print from a Web App using Firefox, which have been the same size for years. Until the last month (while on 20.04), all the files were <100k in size, whereas the one I made today is 3.8MB.

[image]

Another notable difference is that the text in the large PDF can't be selected with the PDF viewer, while it's possible to do with the older/smaller PDFs.

So I guess the new PDF printer curves down texts to vector.

Do you know how I can adjust the "Save to PDF" printer settings to return to the old behavior?

> Note: I tried to install the `printer-driver-cups-pdf` package, and that added another PDF printer to the system. Printing with that, created PDFs of the same size.

Comment: Update: it might be browser related or because Firefox is now a snap: saved the HTML to a file, opened it with Chromium, and it resulted in a 580k file which is "only" 10x bigger than it used to be.

Comment: does other webpages have the same issue? I've did some searching and apparently Firefox might render text to image if font is not available on system, and I guess you're right, snap might be responsible for that

Comment: @Cagri you're right, if I change the font of the same report to plain `sans-serif` (simply in the browser inspector) then the file size shrinks down to 50k and the text becomes selectable.

Comment: But, it's apparently unrelated to the snap itself. I removed the Firefox snap and installed firefox from the official Mozilla PPA, but the filesize is still 3.8MB